# Nodegit: is there a way to check if remote repository exist tor not

Tags: node.js, nodegit

Can we check if the passed repository (e.g.) exists on the git server or not (without cloning) in **Nodegit**?

So I have a use-case where I just need to check if the connection to that git repository can be established or not.
because I don't know which branch users have used master/main.
Is there a direct Nodegit function to test the connection to the top(main/master) branch?

Comment: You've tagged this with a lot of tags, so here's a pure-Git answer: use `git ls-remote`.

Comment: Do we have any built in function in Nodegit by just Passing the URL (SSH one) we get the info!?